# JQuery / Ajax - update URL without refreshing the webpage - should be compatible with IE8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, get

When I first load my webpage, it loads to this URL:

```
/default/
```

Now, when I click the "nextPost" button on the screen (which has an attribute called data-nextPostNumber), this is the code which I have:

```
event.preventDefault();
var nextPost = $(this).attr('data-nextPostNumber');
$("body").load("/default/?postNumber=" + nextPost);
```

So this loads the URL (assuming that nextPost=2)

```
/default/?postNumber=2
```

However, this was loaded using ajax so the actual URL in the URL bar is still

```
/default/
```

What I want to do is get the GET variables in the URL which was loaded through ajax. I have this code (which gets the GET variables in the URL and puts them in a dictionary called params):

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");
    var params = {},
        tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}
```

But this code just gets the GET variables in the URL which is in the URL bar - not the URL which was loaded using Ajax. So, is there a way for me to take the URL which was loaded using Ajax and place that URL in the URL bar? If not, is there any way for me to solve my issue? Please note that I need it to be compatible with IE8 and IE9.

Comment: Please have a look at using the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). This is the direction you should be going. :)

Comment: You should check out [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax), which uses the History API - you're essentially trying to recreate it, it seems

Comment: History API isn't very old, so it has old browser compatibility issues.  IF you are creating a global site, keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new History API method pushState:

```
<input type="button" value="Post #2"
  onclick="history.pushState(null, 'MyWebsite Post #2', 'http://mywebsite.com/?postNumber=2');"  />
```

When you click this button, the location will change to http://mywebsite.com/?postNumber=2 and then you can call your getQueryParams function as follows:

```
getQueryParams(location.search);
```

The pushState will NOT work if you open the page as a file, in another words, it must come from a webserver (it works with localhost)

Comment: Hm, is there any way to solve the issue using a method which supports older browsers such as IE8? I went to this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Browser_compatibility and it says it is not compatible with IE8 or IE9 and that it is not 100% that it is compatible with mobile browsers.

Comment: Sadly no... but you can modify the method that loads the content to parse the query string and store the results in a global variable.

var url = $("body").load("/default/?postNumber=" + nextPost);
$('body').load(url);
window.queryString = getQueryParams(url.substring(url.indexOf('?'));

Comment: what exactly is window.queryString? I can't find any documentation on it when I search for it on Google. Is it just a variable which is saved and can be accessed at anytime on the webpage using JQuery?

Comment: It is a variable... Javascript allows you to store variables in any object (in that case I used the window object)